# Permission denied in firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

In firebase cloud function I am getting access denied on admin-firebase on read or write to realtime database. 
This https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/16 does not solve my problem , App engine default service account rights are set to Editor.

I also have Node.js admin sdk configured with service Account Key and there  everything works as expected.

I have set default security rules in db.

This is an example function

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
admin.database.enableLogging(true);

//event fires properly
exports.sendNotif = functions.database.ref('/messages/{roomId}/{msgKey}')
    .onWrite(event => {
        const message = event.data.val().text;
    //this executes as expected
        console.log(message);

//here I am getting access denied and consequently function timeout after 60 seconds.
        return admin.database().ref('/userFCMTokens').once('value')
            .then(snap => console.log(snap.val()));
    });
```

**and here is log snippet from firebase  realtime db**

```
Realtime connection established.  
2017-06-08T15:19:03.168Z I sendNotif: p:0: connection ready  
2017-06-08T15:19:03.168Z I sendNotif: p:0: {"r":28,"a":"gauth","b":{"cred”:”********************”}}  
2017-06-08T15:19:03.169Z I sendNotif: p:0: Listen on /userFCMTokens for default  
2017-06-08T15:19:03.169Z I sendNotif: p:0: {"r":29,"a":"q","b":{"p":"/userFCMTokens","h":""}}  
2017-06-08T15:19:03.538Z I sendNotif: p:0: from server: {"r":28,"b":{"s":"permission_denied","d":"Access denied."}}  
2017-06-08T15:19:03.538Z I sendNotif: Auth token revoked: permission_denied/Access denied. 
2017-06-08T15:19:03.538Z I sendNotif: c:0:13: Closing realtime connection.  
2017-06-08T15:19:03.538Z I sendNotif: c:0:13: Shutting down all connections  
2017-06-08T15:19:03.538Z I sendNotif: c:0:13:0 WebSocket is being closed
```

**Here without logging on realtime db for brevity:**

```
2017-06-08T15:26:23.164035495Z D sendNotif: Function execution started
2017-06-08T15:26:23.164076543Z D sendNotif: Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions
2017-06-08T15:26:23.539Z I sendNotif: message console logged
2017-06-08T15:27:23.165321703Z D sendNotif: Function execution took 60002 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'
```

**Why I can’t read and write using admin in cloud functions?**

Comment: May I ask why you are using the Firebase Admin SDK instead of using event.data.adminRef.root and then building the path to '/userFCMTokens'?

Comment: I am following this example, https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js. I'll try doing as you suggest.

Comment: I see! Well, this doesn't address why you are getting the permission_denied error, but I would recommend trying event.data.adminRef.root instead of admin.database.ref().

Comment: Can you achieve the same behavior with a new project on the latest SDKs? This looks like a project-specific error; similar to issues I see when an old project that needs to be upgraded from alpha/beta.

Comment: On new project everything works fine. The project where I get this behaviour was created about 4 months ago. But cloud functions were created lately , with npm dependencies "firebase-admin": "~4.2.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.5.7",

Comment: After changing reference from admin.database() to event.data.adminRef.root.child I am still getting access denied.

Answer (score 4):

Try checking permission for “App Engine default service account” on https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project, and ensure that it says “Editor”.

Comment: Yes, I checked that these permissions are set to Editor. Actually it's stated in the second sentence of my question.

Comment: Oops sorry I missed that John. Another thing you can try is: disable and re-enable the cloud functions API at https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard

Comment: I tried that as well, deleted all the functions by submitting empty functions file using firebase CLI, then disabled and enabled API multiple times. Ultimately I abandoned the idea of using firebase functions in this project.

Comment: In case anyone from the future sees this and has the same problem... I was trying to use the `europe-west1` to deploy a http function but this isn't supported. When removing the region configuration (defaults to us-central) this then worked without prompting for a login.

Comment: There were some similar issues reported and it seems that _removing_ function and re-deploying helps to update the necessary permissions. Weird

Answer (score 3):

I needed that anyone from my app could use a callable https function so I had to assign the `All users` to the `Cloud Functions Invoker` permission to the specific function in GCP.

[image]

Comment: 2024: Use https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/details/europe-west1/FUNCTION_NAME -> PERMISSIONS to find this option :)

Answer (score 2):

Firebase/GCP circa mid-2022 has now clear information in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles-predefined-category?hl=en#develop_roles):

```
Firebase Develop Admin         Full read/write access to:
roles/firebase.developAdmin    Google Analytics
                               Firebase App Check
                               ...
                               Cloud Functions for Firebase
                                  (deploying functions requires special configuration)
                               Firebase ML
```

The [special configuration leads to the detail](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/permissions?hl=en#functions) of roles to add to a plain `Editor`: `roles/cloudfunctions.admin` and `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser`. Alternatives are also suggested, like delegating to an `Owner`, but adding the roles is most likely minimal and more secure.