# Need Cloud Functions for Firebase folder permissions when using Codeanywhere

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, codeanywhere

Trying to get started using Firebase functions and have hit a a problem where I can't edit the file that contains the functions code: `/functions/index.js`

My environment is a Codeanywhere container.  I am running these versions of node and NPM:

```
cabox@box-codeanywhere:~$ node -v
v10.10.0
cabox@box-codeanywhere:~$ npm -v
6.4.1
```

I took followed these steps after updating NPM:

1. `sudo npm install -g firebase-tools`
2. `sudo firebase login --no-localhost`
3. (logged in with my G-Suite account associated with Firebase instance)
4. `sudo firebase init`

I have followed these answer from this question to ensure my Google account has the correct permissions: [Permission denied in firebase cloud functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44440897/permission-denied-in-firebase-cloud-functions).  And still no joy.

Unsure whether this is a Codeanywhere peculiarity or common Firebase issue.

Comment: You're saying that you "can't edit the file that contains the functions code". What does that mean? How did you try to edit the file, and what was the result?

Comment: I opened the functions/index.js file. Just uncommented the sample hello world function then saved it.  Codenywhere reports "Error saving file. Permission denied."  Thanks