# Permission denied when calling firebase cloud function

Tags: function, google-cloud-functions, cloud

Created a new Firebase project.
Created a test function, as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started).

Trying to call this function, I get PERMISSION DENIED, both when trying to call it from my flutter app, or directly (403 Forbidden).

Suggestions from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44440897/permission-denied-in-firebase-cloud-functions) didn't help...

This is my second flutter-firebase project. The first one runs just fine, can't see any differences between them that might explain this behaviour. Appreciate any help with this issue :)

my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, found the solution [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam) ("Allowing unauthenticated function invocation"):

"As of January 15, 2020, HTTP functions require authentication by default. You can specify whether a function allows unauthenticated invocation at or after deployment"