# Permission Denied Error for Firebase Cloud Function Login Endpoint

Tags: flutter, firebase, http, google-cloud-functions, permission-denied

I have recently implemented a sign-up and login functionality using Firebase Cloud Functions. The sign-up part is working flawlessly, using the following code:

```
exports.signup = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const { username, password, confirmPassword, uniqueId } = data;
    // Implementation code
});
```

However, when I try to implement the login functionality in a similar manner:

```
exports.login = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const { username, password } = data;
    // Implementation code
});
```

I consistently receive a "permission denied" error on the client side in my Flutter application.

I have made sure to add the "cloud function invoker" role to the server account, but this hasn't resolved the issue.

Here is the client-side code snippet I am using in Flutter:

```
final HttpsCallable callable = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('login');
final result = await callable.call({
    'username': username,
    'password': password,
});
```

I have checked and re-checked my Firestore rules, IAM roles, and permissions, but I can't seem to find the cause of this issue. Since the sign-up part is working, I expected the login part to work in a similar fashion.

Could someone please help me identify what might be causing this "permission denied" error? I'm quite stuck and would greatly appreciate any insights or guidance.

What I have tried and didn't work;

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72400528/14187647

I also tried :https://stackoverflow.com/a/71080061/14187647
which works but I get "This resource is public and can be accessed by anyone on the internet. To remove public access, remove "allUsers" and "allAuthenticatedUsers" from the resource's principals."

Is there any safe way to remove Permission Denied without public access?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should share the entire code of your `login` Callable CF for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The issue is related to the permission panel on Google Cloud and not the code.